SharePoint Online JSON tile custom formatting - loop through available choices
I am creating a custom tile view for a SharePoint Online list. I have a choice field called Result. How can I loop through the available choices to display a button for each of them?
I have found several references for looping through the selected values, but not the available choices.

I don't think it is possible to get all available choices using SharePoint JSON formatting.

Agree with Ganesh Sanap. There is no option to loop through all available values in the choice column.
JSON formatting only could get selected value for the choice column.


That is unfortunate. Thank you.
